# MATLAB string 2 number of table

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

I have a 3-year data in a string `tableformat.txt`. Three of its lines are given below:

```
12-13 Jan -10.5
14-15 Jan -9.992
15-16 Jan -8
```

How to change the 3rd column (`-10.5`, `-9.992` and `-8`) of string to be (`-10.500`, `-9.992` and `-8.000`) of number?

I have made the following script:

```
clear all; clc; 
filename='tableformat.txt'; 
fid = fopen(filename); 
N = 3;
for i = [1:N]
    line = fgetl(fid)
    a = line(10:12);
    na = str2num(a);
    ma(i) = na;
end
ma
```

which gives:

```
ma = -1    -9    -8
```

When I did this change: `a = line(10:15);`, I got:

> Error message: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Suppose your table is having following columns : Year, Month and Val.
T = table(Year, Month, Val);

You can convert the datatype for a column as below:

T.Val = str2double(T.Val);

Comment: from the above script na = str2num(a); If I change  na = str2double(a), the result does not change, still ma = -1 -9 -8 not -10.500, -9.992 and -8.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
clear all;

clc;

filename='tableformat.txt';
filename2='tableformat2.txt';

fid = fopen(filename);
fid2 = fopen(filename2,'w');

formatSpec = '%s %s %6.4f\n';

N = 3;

for row = [1:N]

line = fgetl(fid);
a = strsplit(line,' ');
a{3}=cellfun(@str2num,a(3));
fprintf(fid2, formatSpec,a{1,:});

end

fclose(fid);

fclose(fid2);
```